# Kotlin extension for next Enum value without reflection

Tags: enums, kotlin

I wrote a Kotlin extension which adds `next()` for enum values. But is there an better way to do that?

```
fun <T : Enum<*>> T.next(): T {
    val values = this::class.java.getEnumConstants()
    return if (this.ordinal < values.size - 1) 
            values[this.ordinal + 1] 
        else 
            values[0]
}
enum class Color {Red, Yellow, Green}
Color.Red.next() //Yellow
```

1. Can I achieve that without reflections?
2. If not, how to do that with Kotlins reflection?

The Idea is to iterate from enum value to the next. But only for a specific value, not for whole enum `values()` list. The thing I want to prevent is to add the following to every enum type:

```
fun next() = if (this.ordinal == Color.values().size - 1) 
        Color.values()[0] 
    else 
        Color.values()[this.ordinal + 1]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do that without reflection in Kotlin 1.1 (currently, you can try [the 1.1 RC build](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/02/kotlin-1-1-release-candidate-is-here/)) using the [`enumValues<T>()`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#generic-enum-value-access), which does not use the reflection inside, because it is inlined at call sites instead, and the corresponding `enum` type is placed in the resulting code at compile-time. Example:

```
inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> T.next(): T {
    val values = enumValues<T>()
    val nextOrdinal = (ordinal + 1) % values.size
    return values[nextOrdinal]
}
```

<sup>[(demo of this code)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)  | The `inline` and `reified` are required because `enumValues<T>()` has [`reified T`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).</sup>

An alternative that works with Kotlin 1.0.6 (but still uses [`getDeclaringClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#getDeclaringClass()) from Java reflection):

```
fun <T: Enum<T>> T.next(): T {
    val values = declaringClass.enumConstants
    val nextOrdinal = (ordinal + 1) % values.size
    return values[nextOrdinal]
}
```

Comment: renaming the fun to nextOrFirst() would be more descriptive, sorry to nit :D nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

Based with @hotkey

Add extension functions for: next, nextOrLast , previous, previousOrFirst

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> T.next(): T {
    val values = enumValues<T>()
    val nextOrdinal = (ordinal + 1) % values.size
    return values[nextOrdinal]
}

inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> T.nextOrLast(): T {
    val values = enumValues<T>()
    val nextOrdinal = if ((ordinal + 1) >= values.size) ordinal else (ordinal+1)
    return values[nextOrdinal]
}


inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> T.previousOrFirst(): T {
    val values = enumValues<T>()
    val previousOrdinal = if ((ordinal - 1) < 0) ordinal else (ordinal-1)
    return values[previousOrdinal]
}

inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> T.previous(): T {
    val values = enumValues<T>()
    val previousOrdinal = if ((ordinal - 1) < 0) values.size -1 else (ordinal-1)
    return values[previousOrdinal]
}



enum class Color { Red, Yellow, Green }

fun main() {
    val colors = generateSequence(Color.Yellow) { it.previous() }.take(10)
    colors.forEach(::println)
}
```

[Demo of this code](https://pl.kotl.in/Us2Rv69uj)